How to handle a mix of public and authenticated pages in Next.js
I have a headless WordPress back end with a Next.js front end.
All of my pages essentially have a boolean meta field of “must be logged in to view” which, if checked, makes them hidden unless the user is logged in.
Traditionally (without any auth) I would setup a template at /pages/[…slug].js and use getStaticPaths and getStaticProps to fetch and build the required static pages.
Due to authentication I assume I will need to instead use getServerSideProps on the authenticated pages in order to verify that the user is logged in when the page data is fetched.
However, as far as I can tell, I cannot conditionally use a mix of getStaticProps and getServerSideProps in a single template - you have to pick one or the other.
How do I handle this scenario where all my routes are dynamic, but I want to statically compile all of the public routes?
I thought I would setup a template structure such as:
/pages/[…public].js
/pages/[…private].js

where the public pages (determined by getStaticPaths inside of /pages/[…public].js) would be statically compiled, with the private pages falling back to use the /pages/[…private].js template which contains getServerSideProps
But this doesn’t seem to be a possibility.
How do I achieve this desired mix of statically compiled public pages, and dynamic private pages, where there is no discernible pattern in the URLs?
